# Can I modernize old sliding doors with new frames

Tags: sliding-glass-door

Can I reuse the glass in an old aluminium sliding door and put them into a new modern frame.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you do this? Just replace the entire unit.

Comment: It might be possible if you can use the same manufactures door. I purchased a house that was built by a mobile home manufacturer , a stick built house with several undersized doors. The first one I replaced and it was a bunch of work , the 2nd I found a replacement (the aluminum frames were worn out from metal to metal contact.) I was able to find the same frame and replace the rollers that caused the damage , the first door repair cost close to 800 with me doing the work the 2nd was only about 300 and they were the exact same door. Left as a comment because this is rare it undersized is.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

No, the aluminum door frames are designed for specifically sized panes that work with each manufacturer's proprietary glazing strategy. Finding a door frame that would fit *your* glass would be extremely unlikely; equally unlikely would be that a manufacturer would even supply a door frame by itself. Most aluminum door manufacturers will create custom size units, but trying to get them to fabricate a custom door frame only, to fit your glass, would be highly unlikely and more costly than a complete new unit with the glass.

Also, there is the problem of the surrounding aluminum framework and track, which are designed to work with the original door frame and rollers and would not likely work with a new "modern" door frame.

Also, I suspect that an entirely new unit would actually cost *less* than what you would end up paying, were you able to find a willing supplier.

Also, if your old glass is not tempered safety glass (older units often are not) it should not be used for a door at all.

An alternative might be to have a wood frame designed and built at a custom door and millwork shop; again, likely to be more $$ than an entire new aluminum unit.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I appreciated it. I now know really the only way to go is new doors.  Thanks again.

Comment: Plus you'd never find the rubber sealing strip tht goes around the glass.